# GSheets copying a row in one sheet to another sheet, which contains the same row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets. One is a "Master" sheets which contains a list of all users in the "A" column. The other sheet is a "Test" sheet, which only contains a portion of those users. I want it so that if someone updated a user's row in the "test" sheet, then it will locate which row contains that users name in the "A" column on the "Master" sheet and copy the entire row.

**UPDATE:** Here is my code that worked for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const exportSheet = range.getSheet();
  if (exportSheet.getName() === "Generals" || "Captains" || "Lieutenants" || "Moderators") {
    const sourceRow = exportSheet.getRange(range.getRow(),1,1,exportSheet.getLastColumn());
    const editedData = exportSheet.getRange(range.getRow(),3,1,exportSheet.getLastColumn());
    const masterSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Master");
    const masterValues = masterSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const masterRowIndex = masterValues.findIndex(masterRow => masterRow[0] === sourceRow.getValues()[0][0]) + 1;
    const masterRow = masterSheet.getRange(masterRowIndex,3,sourceRow.getNumRows(),sourceRow.getNumColumns()); 
    editedData.copyTo(masterRow);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use importRange and Vlookup formulas to avoid scripting which is much slower.
Check out what I did in column J to reference the data imported from sheet "master importrange formula" which imports the data from another sheet.
I did it this ways cuz it seemed that the master is another separate document.

Comment: This is the code I currently have: (since my post was deleted and i do not have enough characters to post it here)

https://justpaste.it/4rvop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger, check that the edited sheet's name is `test`, using the corresponding [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). If that's the case, do the following:
- Retrieve the range of the edited row (variable `sourceRow` in the sample below), using [Range.getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow()).
- Retrieve all values from the destination sheet (called `MSTR`), using [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Find the row in the destination sheet whose column A equals column A from the `test` sheet (that is, user is the same). You can use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for that.
- Retrieve the range corresponding to the row index found in previous step, using `getRange`.
- Copy the source row to the destination row, using [Range.copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)).

#### Code sample:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function onEdit(e) {
  const sourceSheetName = "test";
  const destSheetName = "MSTR";
  const range = e.range;
  const editedSheet = range.getSheet();
  if (editedSheet.getName() === sourceSheetName) {
    const sourceRow = editedSheet.getRange(range.getRow(),1,1,editedSheet.getLastColumn());
    const destSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(destSheetName);
    const destValues = destSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const destRowIndex = destValues.findIndex(destRow => destRow[0] === sourceRow.getValues()[0][0]) + 1;
    const destRow = destSheet.getRange(destRowIndex,1,sourceRow.getNumRows(),sourceRow.getNumColumns()); 
    sourceRow.copyTo(destRow);
  }
}
```

#### Edit:

If you want to change the starting column of the range, you have to modify the second parameter from [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns). So, you should retrieve another source range without A-B columns, and that that range to a modified `destRow`, the following way:

```
const firstCol = 3;
const sourceRowToCopy = editedSheet.getRange(range.getRow(),firstCol,1,editedSheet.getLastColumn() - firstCol + 1);
const destRow = destSheet.getRange(destRowIndex,firstCol,sourceRowToCopy.getNumRows(),sourceRowToCopy.getNumColumns());
sourceRowToCopy.copyTo(destRow);
```

Comment: What if I only wanted it to update Columns C, onward?
The reason for this is, on other sheets (i.e. test) I have a query so that it pulls column B's to test sheet. So, with this, its updating the column A onward.

For instance: =QUERY(MSTR!A2:B, "Select A, B Where B='Administrator'")

Comment: @MephobiaYT I edited my answer with a modification to copy only from column C onwards.